# Very Old Stars in the Universe

Tags: star-formation

How could a Star possibly be older than the Universe ? Is this possible or are the calculations off when determining the age of such Stars ? Can a Star exist that formed on its own independent of a Universe ?

Comment: My question is a little different because I would like to know if this is even possible, for a Star to be older than the Universe ? In other words could a Star have formed that is not contained in a Universe ?

Comment: We don't know of any example or physical mechanism to do so. Consider how we humans figure out the universe: By being inside the universe and learning about it from the inside only. It would be exceedingly difficult to learn about anything outside of it.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Excellent point that you make here

Comment: "Is this possible or are the calculations off when determining the age of such Stars?" [There is no dilemma.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19448/7982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't. If we find a star that's "older" than the universe, then either the measurements of the star's age are incorrect, or the measurements of the universe's age are incorrect.